# Where can I find the system log files on my ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS system

Tags: perl

My system is a ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS system

I am working with some perl scripts that use Sys::Syslog to write to the system log.

My questions are :
Where are the log files that contain these written messages ?
How can I look at these files ?

Also I will need to work with copies of these scripts on a Debian system. Will things be much different on Debian ?

So far my google searches have not been helpfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Read `man journalctl rsyslog.conf`. Different on Debian? Who can tell. We know nothing about your Perl scripts

Comment: gnome-system-log in terminal